# Download a pdf from a JS redirected link

Tags: javascript, linux, bash, wget

Is there some way download the following pdf from the command line?

```
http://www.ofsted.gov.uk/provider/files/1295389/urn/EY298883.pdf
```

A simple `wget http://www.ofsted.gov.uk/provider/files/1295389/urn/EY298883.pdf` returns a web page.  However if you go to it in firefox you get a pdf.

Related to [How to get a JS redirected pdf linked from a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663673/how-to-get-a-js-redirected-pdf-linked-from-a-web-page) where I tried to find a python solution.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ I don't think you can do it with wget alone.

Comment: Try this link instead: http://www.ofsted.gov.uk/filedownloading/?id=1295389&type=1&refer=0

Comment: Wget actually does follow the redirect. You can try `curl` to see what you get without following it. The problem is, the redirected target is still not the pdf -- it's some html with JS and the JS redirects you to the pdf.

Comment: @ThorX89 Thank you. You are right. It does seem hard but I feel confident someone brainy on SO will know the answer :)

Comment: [Related](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45959/wget-is-returning-an-html-page-instead-of-original-file)

Comment: Do you really need to do this universally (i.e. -- actually run the JS of the target page)? Cuz you could just grab the link the JS is using,  from the html you get, and wget that.

Comment: This site has the link to the file actually visible on there--it's the one with the text "Please download the requested file here" and a class of .auto_click. You could use (some of) these attributes to find that link, get it's URL, and wget that without simulating a webbrowser and running the JS of the page.

Comment: @ThorX89 I need to do it for hundreds of very similar pages but if there is a nice way to extract the link and get that that would be fine.  Your latest suggestion seems like a very good idea.  Any idea how to do that nicely?

Comment: Yes there is. a) You could try to grep (BAD way to do it) it b) You could use an HTML parsers c) You could use something like one of these simple scripts I wrote, which wrap the Nokogiri html parser and allow you to wget links selected by their text or css respectively. https://github.com/pjump/wgetByCss (I'm gonna change it to just grep_by_css, but I haven't quite gotten to it)

Comment: you asked similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663673/how-to-get-a-js-redirected-pdf-linked-from-a-web-page

Comment: @0x90  Yes the relevant (hard) part for doing this in python is already pointed to in the question. Why the downvote?

Comment: Since you already asked this question.

Comment: @0x90 The other question was about python. This question is about any way from the command line. However if you delete your answer I will delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need a universal answer that simulates a web browser and runs the JS (you need to do this to get a universal solution), but are fine with just finding the download link from the html you get by yourself, then you can:

1. `wget` the page (wget will follow HTTP redirect so that this will give you the target html with the JS that does the download)
2. you then need to parse the HTML and find the link you're looking for
3. you need to `wget` that link

I wrote some simple scripts to do 2,3 for you at https://github.com/pjump/wgetbyCss
In order to use them, you need

- ruby
- the mechanize gem (`gem install mechanize`)

Then you can do:

```
 ./wget_by_link_text 'http://www.ofsted.gov.uk/filedownloading/?id=1295389&type=1&refer=1' "Please download the requested file here"
```

i.e.:

```
   ./wget_by_link_text url link_text [save_as]
```

To get that link by its text. Alternatively, you can use the `wget_by_css` script and get the link by its `.auto_click` class, or some other css selector.

Comment: Thank you! I also got a version working over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663673/how-to-get-a-js-redirected-pdf-linked-from-a-web-page but yours may well be nicer.

Answer (score -1):

in short: **you can't using `wget`/`curl`**

You could use `curl -L` constrains `curl` to follow redirection

```
 curl -L http://www.ofsted.gov.uk/provider/files/1295389/urn/EY298883.pdf
```

But it doesn't work as you can see [curl-FAQ](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html):

> 4.14 Redirects work in browser but not with curl!
>
> curl supports HTTP redirects fine (see item 3.8). Browsers generally
>   support at least two other ways to perform redirects that curl does
>   not:
>
> Meta tags. You can write a HTML tag that will cause the browser to
>   redirect to another given URL after a certain time.
>
> Javascript. You can write a Javascript program embedded in a HTML page
>   that redirects the browser to another given URL.
>
> There is no way to make curl follow these redirects. You must either
>   manually figure out what the page is set to do, or you write a script
>   that parses the results and fetches the new URL.

**So I think bad news, you will have to do it by yourself within a script, see your other question as reference: [How to get a JS redirected pdf linked from a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663673/how-to-get-a-js-redirected-pdf-linked-from-a-web-page)**

---

Consider to use [seleniumhq](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) the queen's website seems to be a hard nut for crawlers.

Comment: Right, that is why you need to follow the doc ... same holds for `wget` and do it in a standalone script.